# What can be done with the terumos and maasros?

Tags: halacha, eretz-yisrael, maaser-tithes, agriculture, teruma

It says at [Star-K](https://www.star-k.org/articles/kashrus-kurrents/kashrus-kurrents-2006/1160/terumos-and-maasros/) that after taking off *terumot* and *maasrot* one should wrap the vegetation in plastic and discard:

> "Wrap the broken or cut-off piece in plastic and discard."

According to Jewish law can anything else be done with it (in this generation)? (What is the minimum thing need to be done with it?)

Can it be put in a compost pile? Can it be left in a field for the wild to take care of it?

related:
[Can one use terumah to light a stove?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30450/can-one-use-terumah-to-light-a-stove)

Comment: For a Kohen? Or a non-Kohen?

Comment: @JoelK both cases

Comment: @hazoriz For a non-kohein, just give it to a kohen and let him deal with it (feed to pets or burn for warmth usually).

Comment: ונותנה בזמן הזה לכל כהן שירצה; בין חבר בין עם הארץ. ואפילו אינו מיוחס רק שמוחזק בכהן. והוא שורפה. ויכול להניחה ולשרפה [עד] שיכול ליהנות ממנה בשעת שריפה. אבל זר אסור ליהנות ממנה בשעת שריפתה אם לא שכהן נהנה עמו. אבל שאר הנאות שאינו מכלה אותה מותרת אפילו לזרים https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%90_%D7%99%D7%98

Comment: @DoubleAA thank you but this is only the teruma part?

Comment: What else are you asking about? Teruma is what that the star-k says to throw out. Everything else [that you own] you just eat

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9419&st=&pgnum=64

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/96200/15256

Answer (score 3):

You have four options

1. Give it to a Kohen who will burn it for warmth or feed it to his pets
2. Bury it
3. Put it into a dedicated compost pot (not mixed with other compost) and discard it once it has decomposed
4. Wrap it and discard it in the garbage

Sources: R Moshe Bloom of the Institute for Torah and the Land of Israel ([here](https://en.toraland.org.il/beit-midrash/halachic-guides/mitzvot-of-the-land/procedure-for-separating-terumot-and-ma-aserot/)), [SA YD 331:19](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.331.19?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), R [Yosef Tzvi Rimon's book on Shmita](https://korenpub.com/collections/rabbi-yosef-tzvi-rimon/products/shemita-from-the-sources-to-practical-halakha) (1st ed, pp. 264ff)

Comment: Also: give it to a kohein so he can bother burying it etc.